# Creating a ContextMenu with a ListView

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a `ListView` filled with a `CustomAdapter` that should display a `ContextMenu` after a long click.

I try to do it like such:

```
// in OnCreateView
ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

registerForContextMenu(list);
```

and

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.todo_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            // Do something
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            // Do something
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my `todo_context_layout.xml` being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/edit" android:title="Edit"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/delete" android:title="Delete"/>
</menu>
```

A long click does trigger the `OnItemLongClickListener` but does not display a context menu. What am I doing wrong?

After reading the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632331/using-contextmenu-with-listview-in-android), I could not find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a context menu you don't need a longclicklistener. Try without this listener.

Comment: Sorry didn't see.. Do you have an additional longclicklistener?

Comment: I have a `OnItemLongClickListener` yes, and it does get called, but not the `onCreateContextMenu` for some reason

Comment: If you want to show a context menu you don't need a longclicklistener. Try without this listener.

Comment: Thank you ! Didn't see your comment, please post it as an answer so I can accept it