# Can't Open Context Menu on Click of Menu Button in Android

Tags: java, android, onlongclicklistener, contextual-action-bar, android-contextmenu

I have a problem with the contextual menu, I have to control "MenuButton" without using of "Contextual Action bar menu (CAB)" when you make a long click and short click displays a context menu.I need to display the contextual menu with using of "Contextual Action bar menu (CAB)".when you make short click on "MenuButton" CAB menu also called on a short click, not a long click. I need to display the contextual menu with a short click. is this possible?

MainActivity.java:

```
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_internal);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_name_file);
    past = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_paste);
    home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_home);
    menu_item = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_more);
    list_in = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_in);

    past.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    fileManager = new FileManager();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new InternalAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
    list_in.setAdapter(adapter);

    list_in.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {

            if (selectCount > 0) {
                if (actionMode == null) {
                    actionMode = InternalActivity.this.startActionMode(callback);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "S>0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                toggleselection(i);
                actionMode.setTitle(selectCount + " " + "Selected");

                if (selectCount == 0) {
                    actionMode.finish();
                }
            } else if (selectCount == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String S = arrayList.get(i).getPathFile();
                File file = new File(S);
                if (arrayList.get(i).isFile() == false) {
                    pathItem = arrayList.get(i).getPathFile();
                    title.setText(pathItem.substring(pathItem.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                    readFile(pathItem);
                } else if (file.canRead()) {
                    Intent intent = FileManager.createIntent(file);
                    if (getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).size() > 0) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });

    list_in.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            if (actionMode == null) {
                actionMode = InternalActivity.this.startActionMode(callback);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "L", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            toggleselection(position);
            actionMode.setTitle(selectCount + " " + "Selected");

            if (selectCount == 0) {
                actionMode.finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    readFile(FileManager.PATH);
    loadFileItem();
}

ArrayList<FileItem> selectedFile = new ArrayList<>();

private void toggleselection(int position) {
    arrayList.get(position).isSelected = !arrayList.get(position).isSelected;
    if (arrayList.get(position).isSelected) {
        selectedFile.add(arrayList.get(position));
        selectCount++;
    } else {
        selectedFile.add(arrayList.get(position));
        selectCount--;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private ActionMode.Callback callback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.internal_context_menu, menu);
        MenuItem mi = menu.getItem(0);
        mi.setTitle(mi.getTitle().toString());
        actionMode = mode;
        selectCount = 0;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.i_de:
                mode.finish();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        if (selectCount > 0) {
            deSelect();
        }
        actionMode = null;
    }
};

private void deSelect() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        arrayList.get(i).isSelected = false;
    }
    selectCount = 0;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

     @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.select_file, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.copy:
            copyFolder(pos);
            break;
        case R.id.delete:
            deleteFolder(pos);
            break;
        case R.id.rename:
            renameFile(pos);
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

    public class InternalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    ArrayList<FileItem> arrayList;

    Context context;

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public InternalAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FileItem> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public FileItem getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_internal_adapter, parent, false);
        viewHolder.imgFolder = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_folder);
        viewHolder.txtNameFile = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_folder);
        viewHolder.txtDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
        viewHolder.imgCreate = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_create);
        viewHolder.view = view.findViewById(R.id.view_internal);
        viewHolder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_image);

        FileItem fileItem = getItem(position);

        if (fileItem.isSelected) {
            viewHolder.view.setAlpha(0.5f);
        } else {
            viewHolder.view.setAlpha(0.0f);
        }

        if (fileItem.isDirectory()) {
            viewHolder.imgFolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_folder_black_24dp);
        } else if (fileItem.isFile()) {
            viewHolder.imgFolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_insert_drive_file_black_24dp);
        }
        viewHolder.txtNameFile.setText(fileItem.getName());
        viewHolder.txtDate.setText(fileItem.getDate());
        viewHolder.imgCreate.setLongClickable(false);
        registerForContextMenu(viewHolder.imgCreate);

        viewHolder.imgCreate.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                unregisterForContextMenu(v);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        viewHolder.imgCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pos = position;
                openContextMenu(v);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgFolder;
        TextView txtNameFile;
        TextView txtDate;
        ImageView imgCreate;
        View view;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm confused - short click = context menu, long click = action menu?

Comment: I normally use recyclers, but I think you've done the registerForContext menu on the viewholder and not the list structure as well (i.e., call it for the list when you set the list up, if you're using a list activity you might need a ref to android.R.id.list), also don't unregister it in onclick (try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632331/using-contextmenu-with-listview-in-android)